# eval-print-last-sexp prints twice on C-j invocation in the scratch buffer

Tags: elisp

The following code print "hello" twice in the *scratch* buffer when the last statement is executed using the **C-j** key (eval-print-last-sexp). Why does it print twice ?

```
(setq tmp "hello")
(print tmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `print` function returns its `OBJECT` argument, so you see "hello" once due to `print` printing it, and then again because `eval-print-last-sexp` prints the `print` return value.